# How to correctly plug external DVD drive to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, dvd, automount, plugins

I have bought an external [DVD driver](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07QG9JN79/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) since modern cases do not have a slot for them any longer. I am using ubuntu 20.04. When plugging, I get an initial detection but then the driver is not mounted:
[image]

How can I properly mount this driver?

Thank you

Comment: Workaround: I've had great luck booting with the device already attached rather that attaching to a running system.

Comment: I got: ```$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: I tried with the driver attached, but I got the same error: initially it is listed in the drivers but then there is no access to it...

Comment: I wrote ubuntu 20.04 in the text...

Comment: I tried on another machine with ubuntu 20.04 and I got the same problem: the driver is listed when I turn on the computer but fails to access the driver. From VLC I got this error: `VLC is unable to open the MRL 'cdda:///dev/sr0'`